# How to Create a Opencv dll for C# application?

Tags: c#

i have `C++ Opencv` code where i need to build it as a `C++ dll` which is suppose to use in `c#` application. do i need to use `"extern "`  spec or do i need to add a reference for the DLL?

How to Create a Opencv dll for C# application ?

How to Achieve this ??

Comment: There is a c# port/wraper, why don't you simply use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Emgu CV is a cross platform .Net wrapper to the Intel OpenCV image
>   processing library. Allowing OpenCV functions to be called from .NET
>   compatible languages such as C#, VB, VC++, IronPython etc.

OpenCV is just a library used by your C/C++ code.

**Refer Following Link:**

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Also Refer [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287781%28vs.71%29.aspx) useful link.

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [OpenCvDotNet](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/)?

This warper should do what you want.